# How i can use a dictionary as a parameter of a class and use it?

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary

I want a dictionary to call as a parameter in a class and wanna use it with the functions which are inside the class.

```
class video_0(data):

def check_internal(self):
    if 'internal' in self.data['video_0']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_sdcard(self):
    if 'sdcard' in self.data['video_0']:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Here data is the dictionary. I tried to do something like this.

```
data = {
"video_3": {
    "internal": {
        "del_status": 1,
        "del_start": 1574164254340.0,
        "del_end": 1574164254345.0,
        "copy_start": 1574162274613.0,
        "copy_end": 1574162274624.0,
        "copied": 1,
        "fail_reason": ""
    },
    "sdcard": {
        "del_status": 1,
        "del_start": 1574829181577.0,
        "del_end": 1574829181577.0,
        "copy_start": 1574162275033.0,
        "copy_end": 1574162275130.0,
        "add_status": 1
    },
    "starttime": 1574162215744.0,
    "duration": 57891,
    "endtime": 1574162273635.0,
    "size": 3754770
},
```

This is the input dictionary i want to use inside the class.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to initialize dictionary as param to init (instance variable), something like below.

```
class video_0:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

rest use same as your methods

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data through the constructor

```
class video_0():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def getData(self):
        return self.data


new_dic = {'Name': 'John'}     
vid = video_0(new_dic)

print(vid.getData())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `__init__` method. To pass parameters to a class object `__init__` method is used. `class ChildClass(ParentClass)` in Python means that `ChildClass` is extending `ParentClass`.

```
class video_0:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def check_internal(self):
        if 'internal' in self.data['video_0']:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_sdcard(self):
        if 'sdcard' in self.data['video_0']:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_internal_copied(self):
        if 'copied' in self.data['video_0']['internal']:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_internal_del_status(self):
        if 'del_status' in self.data['video_0']['internal']:
            return True
        else:
            return False

c = video_0(data)
c.check_internal_copied()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i use 'self.data' inside the class it will change the address of the dictionary and give key error.

Comment: can you paste  the input data in your question?